# Why am I able to change the border color and thickness of my table' <thead> , but not the background color?

Tags: html, css

I am able to change the border styling of the top bar in the table, but I can't it to change the background color no matter what I do. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong? My code is below:

```
<table>
<thead>
            <tr >
        <th>strong>Colour</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Red</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Green</strong></th>
        <th><strong>White</strong></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td align="left">Length (m)</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>0.5</td>
        <td>0.5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left">Weight (kg)</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left">Burn Time (sec)</td>
        <td>60</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left">Light Output (cd)</td>
        <td>200 000</td>
        <td>100 000</td>
        <td>850 000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="left">Visibility at sea level (km)</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>26</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

CSS:

```
table th, table td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

table thead  td, table thead tr {
  background-color: pink;
  border: 4px solid pink;
}
```

Comment: in my browser (IE 11) the head row is pink, is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 2):

Your html code has some syntax erros:

Corrected here and working well:

```
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
<table>
<thead>
            <tr >
        <th><strong>Colour</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Red</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Green</strong></th>
        <th><strong>White</strong></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td align="left">Length (m)</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>0.5</td>
        <td>0.5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left">Weight (kg)</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left">Burn Time (sec)</td>
        <td>60</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left">Light Output (cd)</td>
        <td>200 000</td>
        <td>100 000</td>
        <td>850 000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="left">Visibility at sea level (km)</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>26</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</html>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/XnLr3Fw9MO7jwvJrfjgB?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

It's working for me! Take care with the tags... `<strong>`

```css
table th, table td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

table thead  td, table thead tr {
  background-color: pink;
  border: 4px solid pink;
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
            <tr >
        <th><strong>Colour</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Red</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Green</strong></th>
        <th><strong>White</strong></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td align="left">Length (m)</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>0.5</td>
        <td>0.5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left">Weight (kg)</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left">Burn Time (sec)</td>
        <td>60</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left">Light Output (cd)</td>
        <td>200 000</td>
        <td>100 000</td>
        <td>850 000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="left">Visibility at sea level (km)</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>26</td>
  </tr>
    
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS should include one more rule, for the `<th>` tag:

```
table th, table td {
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

table thead  td, table thead tr, table thead  th {
  background-color: pink;
  border: 4px solid pink;
}
```

Also, you have error in the HTML code - missing starting bracket in `<strong>` tag on line `<th>strong>Colour</strong></th>`.

Check out the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1bvmgaak/).

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dkrybvcm/2/)**

Instead of giving border for tr you can give for td and th

```
table thead  td, table thead tr th { /* added th after tr */
  background-color: pink;
  border: 4px solid pink;
}
```

And try to open and close tags properly to get expected output :)

Answer (score 0):

No need to add so many styles. Apply this.

```css
table th, table thead tr td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

table thead tr {
  background-color: red;
  border: 4px solid pink;
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
            <tr >
        <th><strong>Colour</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Red</strong></th>
        <th><strong>Green</strong></th>
        <th><strong>White</strong></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td align="left">Length (m)</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>0.5</td>
        <td>0.5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left">Weight (kg)</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left">Burn Time (sec)</td>
        <td>60</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left">Light Output (cd)</td>
        <td>200 000</td>
        <td>100 000</td>
        <td>850 000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="left">Visibility at sea level (km)</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>26</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```